# Download vhd of Windows Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, vhd

Is it possible to download a vhd (or vhdx) image of Windows Azure **Cloud Service** and run it locally on my computer in Hyper-V?

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Cloud Services (web/worker roles), you cannot download a vhd. Remember that the running Windows image is created with a baseline image, then your deployment package is attached and your code is executed. If you spin up another instance, it results in the same starting point. There's no way to take the running machine and capture a vhd. VHD-based operation is all part of Virtual Machines. And with those, you *can* download the vhd.